# Fullcalendar agendaDay view - how to display events side by side?

Tags: javascript, html, css, fullcalendar, fullcalendar-2

How can I display events side by side on day agenda view? I've been trying with some javascript positioning inside eventAfterAllRender function, but no success. Like example on picture, how to position events like left align?

[image]

EDIT: Fullcalendar version: 2.4.0.

EDIT: I've changed some CSS and JS code for event width, because I don't want width over entire calendar (on daily view).
I've been trying to implement this code for "repositioning"

```
elements = $('.fc-event-container').find('.fc-v-event');
            var en = 0, cn = 0, i = 0;
            var tzu; 
            var tku; 
            var pzu; 
            var pku; 
            if ($(elements).length > 1) { 
                for (i = 0; i < $(elements).length; i++) {

                    tzu = $(elements[i]).children().children().attr('data-start');
                    de = $(elements[0]).children().children().attr('data-full');


                    st = de.split(' - ');                         
                    if (i > 0) {                                                  
                        zup = $(elements[i - 1]).children().children().attr('data-start');
                        tkuc = $(elements[i]).children().children().attr('data-full');
                        tkud = tkuc.split(' - ');
                        tku = tkud[1];                            
                        if (tzu == zup) {      
                            cn += 1;                                                         
                            $(elements[i]).css('left', 170 * cn + 'px');
                        } if (moment(tkud, "HH:mm").isBefore(moment(st[1], "HH:mm"))) {                                
                            en += 1;                              
                            $(elements[i]).css('left', 170 * en + 'px');
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
```

Comment: Please specify full calendar version you are using ?

Comment: Please also include some code of calendar options. It seems you are creating custom agenda view.

Comment: We can't help you without code.

Comment: P.s. you are running quite an old version of fullCalendar and may not be able to take advantage of features and fixes which could help you with this. Have you considered upgrading? V4 is now the latest

Comment: @ADyson: Since there are quite a lot CSS changes and custom buttons, I haven't yet found time to "translate" it all to the latest version.

Comment: for the events to be as wide apart as they are in your screenshot you must have been doing a fair bit of messing about already. Remove any custom CSS and see if you still have the issue. P.S. What value have you set for [slotEventOverlap](https://fullcalendar.io/docs/v3/slotEventOverlap#v2)?